# How do I convert this C code line into a Simulink block diagram?

Tags: c, matlab, simulink

I have a lot of code in C that I need to convert to a Simulink block diagram. I do not want to use S-Functions because I want the Simulink block diagram to only use basic Simulink blocks, which the user can change without knowing C code. I have been able to convert several lines; however, I am having trouble with the following lines of C code:

```
myVar += myConst1 - myConst2*myConst3
\\ More code changing other variables etc.
myVar -= myConst4
```

My initial idea was to use a feedback loop; however, since `myVar` changes in several other lines of code, this idea would not work.

My second idea was to somehow save `myVar` whenever it is updated, so that the next time `myVar` is accessed, it will be the new value (even in other lines of code). I can not use `simout()` because I need the variable to change dynamically as the model is running. How can I do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using "Data Store Memory", "Data Store Read" and "Data Store Write" blocks are allowed, you can use them for implementation + set the relative order of block execution for these blocks.[image]

Comment: Depending on the field of application, be aware that e. g. the "MISRA AC SLSF" guideline does state following: "Data store memory must not be used to exchange data across subsystem boundaries and must only be used where data exchange is transparent, i. e. within a local subsystem."